# How to generate data model from sql schema in Django?

Tags: python, database, django

Our website uses a PHP front-end and a PostgreSQL database. We don't have a back-end at the moment except phpPgAdmin. The database admin has to type data into phpPgAmin manually, which is error-prone and tedious. We want to use Django to build a back-end.

The database has a few dozen of tables already there. Is it possible to import the database schema into Django and create models automatically?

Comment: That's an odd usage of the terms "front-end" and "back-end".  PHP would be your back-end; it sounds like you're simply talking about building an admin panel to go with it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes it is possible, using the [inspectdb](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

or

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

to get them in into the file

This will look at the database configured in your `settings.py` and outputs model classes to standard output.

As Ignacio pointed out, there is a [guide for your situation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#howto-legacy-databases) in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If each table has an autoincrement integer PK then you can use the [legacy database](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#howto-legacy-databases) instructions.