# Python Django Unknown Command 'SQL'

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm following this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/building-simple-rest-api-mobile-applications/

I'm trying to run SQL by

```
$ python manage.py sql fishes
```

However it says

```
Unknown Command: 'sql'
```

If I type

```
$ python manage.py help
```

I get this, and SQL doesn't appear in the list.

```
Available subcommands:

[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver

[sessions]
    clearsessions

[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver
```

Comment: Yes, indeed that command does not exist any more. You should use a more up-to-date tutorial.

Comment: Is there no alternative?

Comment: The tutorial says "Run `python manage.py sql fishes` to see a preview", so you can probably just ignore that line and carry on the tutorial. It's a good idea to find a more up-to-date tutorial anyway - there might be other things that don't work if you are using a different version of Django to the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that doesn't exist any more, however the command `manage.py dbshell` does.

Generally speaking however, you should try to use models, with load_data etc to preserve the data integrity (as validations etc may happen in models rather then relying on underlying data bits). Or write management commands for any clean up tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, using the [inspectdb](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

or

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

to get them in into the file

This will look at the database configured in your `settings.py` and outputs model classes to standard output.

As Ignacio pointed out, there is a [guide for your situation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#howto-legacy-databases) in the documentation.

Source : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249559/2599596)